# Passing float to a function in C++ appears to change precision

Tags: c++, floating-point

This is a very noob question, but I am curious to know the reason behind this:
-If I debug the following C++ code:

```
void floatreturn(float i){
      //nothing
}

int main(){
    float a = 23.976;
    floatreturn(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Monitoring the passed value of a, it appears to be **23.9759998** when entering floatreturn. As a result, any processing of the value in the function would require to manually tweak the precision. Is there a reason for this, and any way to avoid it?

Comment: What's the change? The decimal part is obviously not going to be `23.976`, but I don't notice any change even when switching to `double`. https://ideone.com/7NgWb0

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/5987.

Comment: `23.976` is a double, not float. Use `float a = 23.976f;` instead. But you'll never get the exactly result in binary floating point

Comment: Try to represent `0.976` as a binary fraction, and you'll see the representation is infinite  (the same reason that the fraction one-third in decimal has an infinite representation of `0.3` with the `3` repeating forever).  So neither `0.976` nor `23.976` can be exactly represented in any floating point type (with a base-2 mantissa) and a nearest approximation is stored.  On your platform, the nearest approximation represented by a `float` is apparently what you are seeing.  (There is also a minor wrinkle that `23.976` has type `double`, and more precision may be lost on converting to `float`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue happened before `floatreturn(a);`.
It happened at `float a = 23.976;`
`floatreturn(a);` is irrelevant.

There are about 2^32 different values that `float` can encode exactly.  23.976 is not one of them.  The nearest encodable `float` is about 23.9759998...

To avoid, use values that can exactly encode as a `float` or tolerate being close - about 1 part in 2<sup>24</sup>

Comment: Thanks Mark for the link and chux for the concise answer.

Comment: Just one more educational point for me: why does cout default to a precision of 3 decimals if we reprint the variable without setting precision for the output? I get that storing the float will always return the closest binary float possible, and that cout is rounding.

Comment: @mv_p What was the _exact_ output you saw?

Comment: with a simple
'float x = 23.976; cout << x;' I see "23.976"